# Sum a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to sum the data of a column only when the payment date is the same.

Here is the data returned:

```
judgment    PaymentDate    interestrate  current1  paymentamount  principalamount
2/1/2008    7/31/2010       9.00          5781.04   -315.07        -270.07
2/1/2008    7/31/2010       9.00          5781.04    272.59         227.59
```

Here is the query:

```
select tb1.judgment, fulldate as PaymentDate, m.interestrate, m.current1, paymentamount, principalamount from master m
            inner join AARS_JudgmentsWithPA tb1 on tb1.jmacct = m.number
            inner join courtcases cc on cc.accountid = m.number
            where m.lastinterest != '2099-01-01 00:00:00.000'
            and tb1.fulldate > tb1.judgment
            and cast(tb1.PrincipalAmount as money) != 0
            and tb1.judgment != ''
            and m.number = 568463
```

For the example data provided I would need those rows combined because the payment date is the same.  So payment amount should be condensed down to be (-270.07 + 227.59) which is -42.48.

I tried to group by on fulldate and sum payment amount but it wanted me to group on every column which then returned both rows again.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SSMS.  I think that is what you're looking for.

Comment: I never heard of a DBMS called *SSMS* - what is that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sql server management studio.

Comment: That's not a DBMS, that's a client tool. The DBMS is SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to speficy an aggregation for columns that you are not grouping by.  For numeric columns that repeat `MIN()`, `MAX()` or `AVG()` would be appropriate.  For string columns `MIN()` or `MAX()` would work.

```
select tb1.judgment, 
       fulldate as PaymentDate, 
       MIN(m.interestrate) AS interestrate, 
       MIN(m.current1) AS current1,
       SUM(paymentamount) AS paymentamount, 
       SUM(principalamount) AS principalamount
from master m
inner join AARS_JudgmentsWithPA tb1 on tb1.jmacct = m.number
inner join courtcases cc on cc.accountid = m.number
where m.lastinterest != '2099-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    and tb1.fulldate > tb1.judgment
        and cast(tb1.PrincipalAmount as money) != 0
        and tb1.judgment != ''
        and m.number = 568463
group by tbl.judgment, fulldate
```

Another option would be to group on columns that repeat and aggregate the rest:

```
select tb1.judgment, 
       fulldate as PaymentDate, 
       m.interestrate, 
       m.current1, 
       SUM(paymentamount) AS paymentamount, 
       SUM(principalamount) AS principalamount
from master m
inner join AARS_JudgmentsWithPA tb1 on tb1.jmacct = m.number
inner join courtcases cc on cc.accountid = m.number
where m.lastinterest != '2099-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    and tb1.fulldate > tb1.judgment
        and cast(tb1.PrincipalAmount as money) != 0
        and tb1.judgment != ''
        and m.number = 568463
group by tbl.judgment, fulldate, m.interestrate, m.current1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing nothing, when you are using an aggregate function, in this case sum(), you have to group by every other non-aggregate column. The first few sentenced explain in a pretty verbose fashion: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html and a list of functions that require you to group by: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: There has to be a way around it, I cannot group by every other column because then it returns back two rows which defeats the purpose of trying to sum the rows where the payment date is the same.

Comment: You can disable it, but if you are grouping every column and getting back more than one row, that means you are getting back data that has unique values. This will cause exactly what you are seeing and in this case your principalamount fields have differing data so you get back one row for each unique piece of data.

Comment: Alright I understand now.  I removed the principalamount column all together as it wasn't necessary in this calculation.  And now it returns one single row.